# Why my laptop cpu I5-1135G7 have base speed is 1.38 ghz while the speed can go higher?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5, cpu-speed

Sometimes my cpu can even go down to 0.30 ghz. Does anyone know why because this is getting a bit annoying for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlTT7.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1.38GHz is the pessimistic "it should work at least at this speed" rating. Depending on temperature and workload it may go higher, and it may also go much higher while on mains power.

Comment: Answered here:  https://superuser.com/a/1711828/231418

Comment: @MubeenShahid that answer may solve the "how" of how to lock the cpu at it's rated speed, but not the "why" of why it does it in the first place which at a glance appears to be the focus of this particular question.